# How to disable NestJS Logger, based on env?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm using logger option in `NestFactory.create()` method to control Logger's log levels in production mode, but it's not working with `ENV='production'`, still showing `Logger.log()` messages

```
const bootstrap = async () => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
    logger:
      env.ENV == 'development'
        ? ['debug', 'error', 'log', 'verbose', 'warn']
        : ['error', 'warn'],
  });

  app.enableCors();

  app.use(helmet());
  app.set('trust proxy', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I create my custom logger
2. Inject it in the root module.

Within the constructor of the custom logger, that is where I put my condition using the **setLogLevels** function. I set the levels to empty, so it can ignore any console stdout.

```js
import { ConsoleLogger, Injectable, LoggerService } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppLogger extends ConsoleLogger implements LoggerService {
  constructor(
    context: string,
    options?: {
      timestamp?: boolean;
    },
  ) {
    super(context, options);
    /***
     * @condition to check if it is in testing mode
     */
    if (condition) {
      this.setLogLevels([]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Env variables are accessed with **`process.env`** global object, in Node.js.

The following example is working as expected, reading `process.env.ENV`:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger: process.env.ENV === 'production' ? ['warn', 'error'] : ['debug', 'log', 'verbose']
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

`yarn start` display **all initialization logs**, whereas `ENV=production yarn start` shows **no initialization logs**.

Comment: its not the env parsing issue, env parsing is correct https://github.com/HedCET/twitter-bot/blob/master/src/main.ts#L18

Comment: I just cloned your repository and tested your code. It is working as expected. Starting with `ENV='development'`, I can see the initialization logs of NestJS (e.g. "Starting Nest application...") whereas with `ENV='production'` I only see the errors (MoongoseModule, "unable to connect to the database").

(I installed all packages using "yarn" and created an empty dotenv file `.development`, then started with both configuration)

Comment: I solved it by using Logger as dependency injection in other services

Comment: @lintocheeran, could please give your own answer the answer?